# Why is my for loop an infinite loop (C)?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 25
#define LINE 10

#define BYTES_A_ROW         ((int)10)
#define ADDR_COLUMN_WIDTH   ((int)(2 * sizeof(void *)) - 2)  //char size of an address =$
#define BYTE_COLUMN_WIDTH   ((int)(BYTES_A_ROW * 3) - 1) // 1 bytes is 2 hex chars + s$
#define COLUMN_SEPARATOR    " "

int main() {
    typedef unsigned char byte_t;
    byte_t data[DATA_SIZE];
    int i;
    int j;
    int remainder = DATA_SIZE % LINE;

    // print table header
    printf("\n%-*s", ADDR_COLUMN_WIDTH, "Address");
    printf("%s", COLUMN_SEPARATOR);
    printf("%-*s", BYTE_COLUMN_WIDTH, "Bytes");
    printf("%s", COLUMN_SEPARATOR);
    printf("%-*s\n", BYTES_A_ROW, "Chars");

    for (i = 0; i < ADDR_COLUMN_WIDTH; i++)
        printf("-");
    printf("%s", COLUMN_SEPARATOR);
    for (i = 0; i < BYTE_COLUMN_WIDTH; i++)
        printf("-");
    printf("%s", COLUMN_SEPARATOR);
    for (i = 0; i < BYTES_A_ROW; i++)    // number of chars is char-column is exactly$
        printf("-");
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE - remainder; i = +LINE) {
        printf("%p ", (void*)&data[i]);
        for (j = i; j < i + LINE; j++) {
            printf("%02x ", data[j]);
        }
        for (j = i; j < i + LINE; j++) {
            if (isprint(data[j])) {
                printf("%c", data[j]);
            } else {
                printf(".");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

For some reason my fourth for loop keeps looping. The variable `i` stays `10`... Why isn't it incremented so it becomes `20` and escapes the loop? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Your indentation style is catastrophic.  Use a classic consistent style for better readability and fewer bugs.  adding spaces around binary operators such as `=` make the bug obvious: `i = +LINE` instead of `i += LINE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `i+=LINE` instead of `i=+LINE`.

Answer (score 3):

In the loop

```
for(i=0; i<DATA_SIZE-remainder; i=+LINE)
```

You are assigning `LINE` to `i` in each iteration. `+` in `+LINE` is a unary `+` operator.
 You need to change `i=+LINE` to `i += LINE` to increment `i` by `LINE` in each iteration.